# Linux TCP payload filter

Tags: linux-networking, tcp

I use nftables, but it hasn't got anything like iptables' string nor u32 match, so it couldn't reliably gather payload offset.
If not via nftables' raw payloads, how could I analyze TCP payload efficiently without any user space bottlenecks? (nfqueue is not an answer for performance reasons)

Are there any techniques to do such filtering at the kernel level? Even marking suitable packets is enough for me - the rest of stuff could be easily done at the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

There's already kernel code available able to handle arbitrary string match, still in kernel context during packet path, why not reuse it?
*iptables* is not going anywhere. What might *maybe* disappear someday is the legacy kernel API for *iptables*, leaving only [*iptables-nft*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/xtables-nft.8.html) around, still able to use *xtables* modules such as the [*string*](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions#string) match [module](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STRING.html). Using [*iptables-legacy*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/xtables-legacy.8.html) or *iptables-nft* along *nftables* will have the same result below.

It's possible to use marks to pass messages around various network subsystems in the packet path, including from *nftables* to *iptables* and then back from *iptables* to *nftables*.

This [Priority within hook](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Netfilter_hooks#Priority_within_hook) table can help:

> | nftables Families | Typical hooks | nft Keyword | Value | Netfilter Internal Priority | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | [...] |  |  |  |  |  |
> | inet, ip, ip6 | all | mangle | -150 | NF_IP_PRI_MANGLE | Mangle operation |
> | inet, ip, ip6 | prerouting | dstnat | -100 | NF_IP_PRI_NAT_DST | Destination NAT |
> | inet, ip, ip6, arp, netdev | all | filter | 0 | NF_IP_PRI_FILTER | Filtering operation, the filter table |
> | [...] |  |  |  |  |  |

One just needs to register *nftables* twice for each *iptables*' built-in chain to be involved: once with a priority just before *iptables*', once with a priority just after *iptables*'. For example with a filter/OUTPUT chain with *iptables* priority 0, one can use -5 and 5 around it. More details in [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467076/how-set-mark-option-works-on-netfilter-iptables) [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419851/when-and-how-to-use-chain-priorities-in-nftables) Unix/Linux SE Q/A where I made answers.

---

Artificial example (adapted from an example in [`iptables-extensions(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions#string)) mixing *nftables* and *iptables*, where the system should drop locally initiated DNS requests for the specific DNS address [www.netfilter.org](http://www.netfilter.org), presented in hook priority order (caveat: UDP only, works only without the presence of any IPv4 or IPv6 option/headers in the outgoing packet because of the fixed range, but the range can be relaxed to accomodate for this):

```sh
nft add table inet mytable
nft add chain inet mytable outputbefore '{ type filter hook output priority -5; policy accept; }'
nft add rule inet mytable outputbefore udp dport 53 meta mark set 1

iptables -I OUTPUT -m mark --mark 1 -m string --algo bm --from 40 --to 57 --hex-string '|03|www|09|netfilter|03|org|00|' -j MARK --set-mark 2
ip6tables -I OUTPUT -m mark --mark 1 -m string --algo bm --from 60 --to 77 --hex-string '|03|www|09|netfilter|03|org|00|' -j MARK --set-mark 2

nft add chain inet mytable outputafter '{ type filter hook output priority 5; policy accept; }'
nft add rule inet mytable outputafter meta mark 2 drop
```

The goal here is to have *iptables* handle only the part that can't be handled by *nftables* and only do the minimal work: issue a return value through a mark, leaving back *nftables* in charge of the fate of the packet:

- *nftables* sets the packet's mark to 1 to "ask" *iptables* to perform some work
- *iptables* (or *ip6tables*) performs a string match only if it "received" a mark of 1, to spare CPU use, and "answers" 2 if the string matched in such case
- *nftables* drops the packet only if it "received" a mark of value 2 (thus deleting the *iptables* rules also disables the effect)

---

Notes:

- Caveat

  The communication mechanism between *nftables* and *iptables* is through packet marks (or could also be through *conntrack* connmarks). While it's possible to write to and read from only a few bits of the mark (by using the optional mask on the mark and adequate bitwise operations), every users of marks must then respect some allocation convention for the ownership of bits in the mark. Without this, tools will interfere with each others when handling marks. For example *firewalld* uses marks for handling redirections in rules, so this example might not be compatible with *firewalld*, even if it uses its own tables when using the *nftables* backend.
- Some easy cases can use [raw payloads](https://manpages.debian.org/nft.8#RAW_PAYLOAD_EXPRESSION)

  This specific example above, with *fixed* offsets, could have been implemented with *nftables*. It's when there's an arbitrary offset to find the data (best used with iptables' *string* match) or a complex method to compute such offset (best used with iptables' *u32* match) that *nftables* can't be used.

  Here's the equivalent replacing all rules above with a single rule using raw payloads. Syntax allows a maximum of 128 bits only, but here 19x8=152 bits are needed so it has to be split into two raw payloads (128 bits + 24 bits). `printf`, `xxd` and `cut` are also used for some help:

  ```sh
  nft add table inet mytable
  nft add chain inet mytable output '{ type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept; }'
  nft add inet mytable output udp dport 53 \
      @th,160,128 0x$(printf '\3%s\11%s\3%s\0' www netfilter org | xxd -p | cut -c-32) \
      @th,288,24 0x$(printf '\3%s\11%s\3%s\0' www netfilter org | xxd -p | cut -c33-) \
      drop
  ```

  With the output of `printf '\3%s\11%s\3%s\0' www netfilter org | xxd -p` being:

  ```
    03777777096e657466696c746572036f726700
  ```

  to get the two raw payloads:

  ```
  0x03777777096e657466696c746572036f
                                  0x726700
  ```
- other methods are probably available

  - *iptables* can call an eBPF object (anyway only recent kernels allow (finite) loops to try and implement some algorithms easily), *nftables* lacks this feature. So it's again with a mark and *iptables*.
  - such eBPF object could be [used with *XDP*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032878/ebpf-packet-filter-on-payload-matching) or *tc* but it might be too early in the packet path (eg: no stateful NAT available) and requires actual programming rather than administration. Anyway it's again communication through a mark if decisions have to be handled with *nftables*.